# Sublime LaTexTools - Go to first error keybinding

Tags: errors, sublime-text

I am using Sublime Text 3 on Mac OS X 10.11.1 and the latest version of LaTexTools.
I can't find a keybinding that goes to the first error. 
Does it exist? If not can it be created in a simple way or we have to ask the developer to it?

Comment: Do you mean something beyond ST's default `f4` and `shift + f4` behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Sublime Text `F4` goes to the next error and `shift + F4` goes to the previous error.